# Integral expansion of a ket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation, calculus, linear-algebra

I'm taking my first quantum physics course and I've been seeing a lot of stuff like $|\psi\rangle = \int d\phi |\phi\rangle \langle \phi | \psi \rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle = \int d^3 r |r\rangle \langle r | \psi \rangle$ but I have no idea where these integral "expansions" (for lack of a better word) come from...for example, how would you derive a similar integral expression for $\langle x | \psi \rangle = \psi (x)$?

Comment: This should be explained in **any** book or course on QM.

Comment: This is usually called "resolution of the unity."

Comment: @TobiasFünke our course is an introductory course, so we don't actually use bra-ket notation. I'm asking this for my own understanding.

Comment: @DanDan0101 thanks! I'll look into that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the decomposition of the identity operator. Given any orthonormal basis $|i\rangle$ of the Hilbert space, the identity operator can be written as
$$
{\mathbb 1} = \sum_i |i\rangle \langle i | 
$$
In your case, you have a continuous basis $|x\rangle$, so the decomposition looks like
$$
{\mathbb 1} = \int dx |x\rangle \langle x | 
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Could you expand a little further as to why $1=\sum |i\rangle \langle i |$? I have a pretty solid understanding of linear algebra and orthonormal bases, but I'm just starting to get familiar with bra-ket notation so I'm a little confused by this identity. I know that $\langle i | = |i\rangle^{\dagger}$, but that's about all I understand from this...

Comment: You can think of $\mid i\rangle\langle i\mid$ as a projection operator onto $\mid i\rangle$.

Comment: @DanDan0101 I've just done some sample calculations and I can see that this is true. Just to confirm, though: $$\sum |i \rangle \langle i | = \begin {bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \end{bmatrix} _ {\mathbb{R}^3 \ standard}$$

Comment: If the $\mid i\rangle$ form a complete orthonormal basis, then the sum of the projection operators is $1$, which we take to mean the identity operator. If our space is 3-dimensional, then it can be represented by the $3\times3$ identity matrix as you have shown.

Comment: @DanDan0101 I don't quite get the concept that $|i \rangle \langle i|$
 is a projection... wouldn't the following just be true:

$$|i \rangle \langle i| = \begin{bmatrix}i_1\\i_2\\i_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}i_1 ^* & i_2 ^ * & i_3 ^ * \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} i_1i_1 ^ *&i_1i_2 ^ * & i_1i_3 ^ * \\ i_2i_1 ^ * &i_2i_2 ^ * & i_2i_3 ^ * \\ i_3i_1 ^ * &i_3i_2 ^ * & i_3i_3 ^ * \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Never mind, I just remembered that projection is an outer product, and that's what $|i \rangle \langle i |$ is.